# Country list in profiles only shows US

Tags: drupal, profile

We recently suffered a DoS attack which forced us to recreate our site from a fresh latest Drupal installation, install DoS protection and move the site back to its original location. We did not upgrade CiviCRM (currently using 4.6.0).

The site is back on line and working fairly well, but now only "United States" shows in profiles and contact edit forms. The table civicrm_country looks ok, with all countries correctly listed. Any ideas?

Thanks

Miguel Peirano

Answer (score 5):

It is fixed. It was as simple as returning to Admin > Localization and re-enabling the country list. Sorry about asking before thinking :-)

Miguel